# redux is not re-rendering component with React 18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, use-effect

I have a custom hook which handles global data fetching based on user authentication.
the hook is like this:

```
const userState = useSelector(state => state.user.state)

useEffect(() => {
    if(userState === "authenticated") doSomething()
    if(userState === "unauthenticated") doSomething()
    if(userState === "loading") doSomething()
}, [userState])
```

but since I am using React 18 strict mode (in NextJS), the useEffect only runs twice with `userState === "loading"` value and won't run when state updates.

I'm not sure if I should give more details of my code. If you need, tell me and I will edit the question. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React 18 had some problems with the version of react-redux <= 7.2.7, so make sure you update that to 7.2.8 or the new react-redux 8 beta (which is specificaly designed for React 18)

Answer (score 0):

In React 18 with strict mode , after component mounts ,React immediately simulates  unmounting and remounting the component (only in **development environment**)
[check react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state)

I assume removing the strict mode will fix your problem .
in order to have consistent code and preventing unsafe lifecycles from happening, use `next lint` instead.